# Is a single whitespace/linefeed/carriage return/horizontal tab belong to json?

Tags: json

Is a single whitespace/linefeed/carriage return/horizontal tab belong to json?

https://www.json.org/json-en.html

[image]

but in V8 it will got an error

```js
JSON.parse(' ')
```

Comment: All your whitespace are belong to us. No, seriously - what do you mean by that exactly? Is it maybe "WS" at the bottom in the box to the right, what you are looking for? The numbers are codepoints for whitespace, tab ...

Comment: I think it fails, because there is no content in string. Try `'" "'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From json.org

> Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens

Your whitespace isn't surrounded by tokens